# How to install ruby 1.9.3 under rvm in Linux Mint 12

Tags: ruby, rvm, linux-mint

I'm trying to install ruby 1.9.3 under rvm, but got this problem

I have been updated my rvm, have been installed all rvm's requirements, but it doesn't helped me.

Same problem I'm got when tried to install 1.9.2

Maybe, someone can help me? I'm using Linux Mint 12.
System been installed on VIA Epia SN18000 Processor VIA C7. Maybe problem is here.

Below is my `~/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p318/make.log`

---

```
    [2012-03-21 00:22:52] make 
        CC = gcc
        LD = ld
        LDSHARED = gcc -shared
        CFLAGS = -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=pointer-arith -Werror=write-strings -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Werror=implicit-function-declaration  -fPIC 
        XCFLAGS = -include ruby/config.h -include ruby/missing.h -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT
        CPPFLAGS =   -I. -I.ext/include/i686-linux -I./include -I.
        DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-soname,libruby.so.1.9  
        SOLIBS = -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm  
    compiling main.c
    compiling dmydln.c
    compiling dmyencoding.c
    compiling version.c
    compiling dmyversion.c
    compiling miniprelude.c
    compiling array.c
    compiling bignum.c
    compiling class.c
    compiling compar.c
    compiling complex.c
    compiling dir.c
    compiling dln_find.c
    compiling enum.c
    compiling enumerator.c
    compiling error.c
    compiling eval.c
    compiling load.c
    compiling proc.c
    compiling file.c
    compiling gc.c
    compiling hash.c
    compiling inits.c
    compiling io.c
    compiling marshal.c
    compiling math.c
    compiling node.c
    compiling numeric.c
    compiling object.c
    compiling pack.c
    compiling parse.c
    compiling process.c
    compiling random.c
    compiling range.c
    compiling rational.c
    compiling re.c
    compiling regcomp.c
    compiling regenc.c
    compiling regerror.c
    compiling regexec.c
    compiling regparse.c
    compiling regsyntax.c
    compiling ruby.c
    compiling safe.c
    compiling signal.c
    compiling sprintf.c
    compiling st.c
    compiling strftime.c
    compiling string.c
    compiling struct.c
    compiling time.c
    compiling transcode.c
    compiling util.c
    compiling variable.c
    compiling compile.c
    compiling debug.c
    compiling iseq.c
    compiling vm.c
    compiling vm_dump.c
    compiling thread.c
    compiling cont.c
    compiling ./enc/ascii.c
    compiling ./enc/us_ascii.c
    compiling ./enc/unicode.c
    compiling ./enc/utf_8.c
    compiling newline.c
    compiling ./missing/strlcpy.c
    compiling ./missing/strlcat.c
    compiling ./missing/setproctitle.c
    compiling addr2line.c
    compiling dmyext.c
    linking miniruby
    rbconfig.rb updated
    generating enc.mk
    compiling dln.c
    compiling encoding.c
    generating prelude.c
    compiling prelude.c
    linking static-library libruby-static.a
    linking shared-library libruby.so.1.9.1
    generating encdb.h
    encdb.h unchanged
    making enc
    make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sergey/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p125'
    compiling ./enc/encdb.c
    linking encoding encdb.so
    compiling ./enc/big5.c
    linking encoding big5.so
    compiling ./enc/cp949.c
    linking encoding cp949.so
    compiling ./enc/emacs_mule.c
    linking encoding emacs_mule.so
    compiling ./enc/euc_jp.c
    linking encoding euc_jp.so
    compiling ./enc/euc_kr.c
    linking encoding euc_kr.so
    compiling ./enc/euc_tw.c
    linking encoding euc_tw.so
    compiling ./enc/gb2312.c
    linking encoding gb2312.so
    compiling ./enc/gb18030.c
    linking encoding gb18030.so
    compiling ./enc/gbk.c
    linking encoding gbk.so
    compiling ./enc/iso_8859_1.c
    linking encoding iso_8859_1.so
    compiling ./enc/iso_8859_2.c
    linking encoding iso_8859_2.so
    compiling ./enc/iso_8859_3.c
    linking encoding iso_8859_3.so
    compiling ./enc/iso_8859_4.c
    linking encoding iso_8859_4.so
    compiling ./enc/iso_8859_5.c
    linking encoding iso_8859_5.so
    compiling ./enc/iso_8859_6.c
    linking encoding iso_8859_6.so
    compiling ./enc/iso_8859_7.c
    linking encoding iso_8859_7.so
    compiling ./enc/iso_8859_8.c
    linking encoding iso_8859_8.so
    compiling ./enc/iso_8859_9.c
    linking encoding iso_8859_9.so
    compiling ./enc/iso_8859_10.c
    linking encoding iso_8859_10.so
    compiling ./enc/iso_8859_11.c
    linking encoding iso_8859_11.so
    compiling ./enc/iso_8859_13.c
    linking encoding iso_8859_13.so
    compiling ./enc/iso_8859_14.c
    linking encoding iso_8859_14.so
    compiling ./enc/iso_8859_15.c
    linking encoding iso_8859_15.so
    compiling ./enc/iso_8859_16.c
    linking encoding iso_8859_16.so
    compiling ./enc/koi8_r.c
    linking encoding koi8_r.so
    compiling ./enc/koi8_u.c
    linking encoding koi8_u.so
    compiling ./enc/shift_jis.c
    linking encoding shift_jis.so
    compiling ./enc/utf_16be.c
    linking encoding utf_16be.so
    compiling ./enc/utf_16le.c
    linking encoding utf_16le.so
    compiling ./enc/utf_32be.c
    linking encoding utf_32be.so
    compiling ./enc/utf_32le.c
    linking encoding utf_32le.so
    compiling ./enc/windows_1251.c
    linking encoding windows_1251.so
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sergey/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p125'
    making srcs under enc
    make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sergey/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p125'
    make[1]: Nothing to be done for `srcs'.
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sergey/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p125'
    generating transdb.h
    transdb.h unchanged
    making trans
    make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sergey/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p125'
    compiling ./enc/trans/transdb.c
    linking transcoder transdb.so
    compiling ./enc/trans/big5.c
    linking transcoder big5.so
    compiling ./enc/trans/chinese.c
    linking transcoder chinese.so
    compiling ./enc/trans/emoji.c
    linking transcoder emoji.so
    compiling ./enc/trans/emoji_iso2022_kddi.c
    linking transcoder emoji_iso2022_kddi.so
    compiling ./enc/trans/emoji_sjis_docomo.c
    linking transcoder emoji_sjis_docomo.so
    compiling ./enc/trans/emoji_sjis_kddi.c
    linking transcoder emoji_sjis_kddi.so
    compiling ./enc/trans/emoji_sjis_softbank.c
    linking transcoder emoji_sjis_softbank.so
    compiling ./enc/trans/escape.c
    linking transcoder escape.so
    compiling ./enc/trans/gb18030.c
    linking transcoder gb18030.so
    compiling ./enc/trans/gbk.c
    linking transcoder gbk.so
    compiling ./enc/trans/iso2022.c
    linking transcoder iso2022.so
    compiling ./enc/trans/japanese.c
    linking transcoder japanese.so
    compiling ./enc/trans/japanese_euc.c
    linking transcoder japanese_euc.so
    compiling ./enc/trans/japanese_sjis.c
    linking transcoder japanese_sjis.so
    compiling ./enc/trans/korean.c
    linking transcoder korean.so
    compiling ./enc/trans/single_byte.c
    linking transcoder single_byte.so
    compiling ./enc/trans/utf8_mac.c
    linking transcoder utf8_mac.so
    compiling ./enc/trans/utf_16_32.c
    linking transcoder utf_16_32.so
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sergey/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p125'
    making encs
    make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sergey/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p125'
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sergey/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p125'
    configuring -test-/add_suffix
    configuring -test-/array/resize
    configuring -test-/bug-3571
    configuring -test-/bug-3662
    configuring -test-/funcall
    configuring -test-/load/dot.dot
    configuring -test-/old_thread_select
    configuring -test-/st/numhash
    configuring -test-/string
    configuring -test-/wait_for_single_fd
    configuring bigdecimal
    configuring continuation
    configuring coverage
    configuring curses
    Aborted
    make: *** [exts.mk] Error 134
```

Next I tried to build ruby 1.9.3-125 from sources and when I enter "make && make install" got next:

```
make && make install
    CC = gcc
    LD = ld
    LDSHARED = gcc -shared
    CFLAGS = -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=pointer-arith -Werror=write-strings -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Werror=implicit-function-declaration 
    XCFLAGS = -include ruby/config.h -include ruby/missing.h -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT
    CPPFLAGS =   -I. -I.ext/include/i686-linux -I./include -I.
    DLDFLAGS =  
    SOLIBS = 
generating encdb.h
encdb.h unchanged
making enc
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sergey/tmp/ruby-1.9.3-p125'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `enc'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sergey/tmp/ruby-1.9.3-p125'
making srcs under enc
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sergey/tmp/ruby-1.9.3-p125'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `srcs'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sergey/tmp/ruby-1.9.3-p125'
generating transdb.h
transdb.h unchanged
making trans
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sergey/tmp/ruby-1.9.3-p125'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `./enc/trans'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sergey/tmp/ruby-1.9.3-p125'
making encs
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sergey/tmp/ruby-1.9.3-p125'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sergey/tmp/ruby-1.9.3-p125'
configuring curses
./ext/extmk.rb:54: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [i686-linux]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
./ext/extmk.rb:54: [BUG] object allocation during garbage collection phase
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [i686-linux]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0009 p:---- s:0085 b:0085 l:000084 d:000084 CFUNC  :[]
c:0008 p:0041 s:0080 b:0080 l:000079 d:000079 METHOD ./ext/extmk.rb:54
c:0007 p:0485 s:0067 b:0067 l:000066 d:000066 METHOD ./ext/extmk.rb:151
c:0006 p:0046 s:0045 b:0045 l:001aac d:000044 BLOCK  ./ext/extmk.rb:468
c:0005 p:---- s:0042 b:0042 l:000041 d:000041 FINISH
c:0004 p:---- s:0040 b:0040 l:000039 d:000039 CFUNC  :each
c:0003 p:1285 s:0037 b:0037 l:001aac d:000af0 EVAL   ./ext/extmk.rb:464
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:001aac d:001aac TOP   

-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
./ext/extmk.rb:464:in `<main>'
./ext/extmk.rb:464:in `each'
./ext/extmk.rb:468:in `block in <main>'
./ext/extmk.rb:151:in `extmake'
./ext/extmk.rb:54:in `extract_makefile'
./ext/extmk.rb:54:in `[]'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
./miniruby() [0x81b2681]
./miniruby() [0x8091e56]
./miniruby(rb_bug+0x31) [0x8092e41]
./miniruby(rb_newobj+0x90) [0x80aa9a0]
./miniruby() [0x8153da6]
./miniruby(rb_usascii_str_new_cstr+0x22) [0x8158852]
./miniruby(rb_id2str+0x156) [0x80f4386]
./miniruby(rb_id2name+0xf) [0x80f689f]
./miniruby() [0x81b1f1a]
./miniruby() [0x81b2606]
./miniruby() [0x8091e56]
./miniruby(rb_bug+0x31) [0x8092e41]
./miniruby() [0x8145554]
[0x4002040c]
./miniruby(st_free_table+0x2c) [0x814cefc]
./miniruby() [0x80a7d68]
./miniruby() [0x80a9424]
./miniruby() [0x80a9b2b]
./miniruby() [0x80a9dbf]
./miniruby(rb_str_buf_new+0xaf) [0x815b2cf]
./miniruby() [0x8120425]
./miniruby(rb_reg_prepare_re+0xc9) [0x8122c79]
./miniruby(rb_reg_search+0x6a) [0x812377a]
./miniruby() [0x815f29f]
./miniruby() [0x819f3d5]
./miniruby() [0x81aec24]
./miniruby() [0x81a42bb]
./miniruby() [0x81a9599]
./miniruby(rb_yield+0x42) [0x81af592]
./miniruby(rb_ary_each+0x4c) [0x805e6dc]
./miniruby() [0x81aec24]
./miniruby() [0x81a42bb]
./miniruby() [0x81a9599]
./miniruby(rb_iseq_eval_main+0xa6) [0x81affa6]
./miniruby() [0x80955e4]
./miniruby(ruby_run_node+0x59) [0x8097929]
./miniruby() [0x8059c0a]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3) [0x400d2113]
./miniruby() [0x8059c2d]

-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: ./ext/extmk.rb

* Loaded features:

    0 enumerator.so
    1 /home/sergey/tmp/ruby-1.9.3-p125/rbconfig.rb
    2 mkmf.rb
    3 /home/sergey/tmp/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/fileutils.rb
    4 /home/sergey/tmp/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/shellwords.rb
    5 /home/sergey/tmp/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/optparse.rb
    6 /home/sergey/tmp/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/optparse/shellwords.rb

* Process memory map:

08048000-08254000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2113967    /home/sergey/tmp/ruby-1.9.3-p125/miniruby
08254000-08255000 r--p 0020b000 08:01 2113967    /home/sergey/tmp/ruby-1.9.3-p125/miniruby
08255000-08256000 rw-p 0020c000 08:01 2113967    /home/sergey/tmp/ruby-1.9.3-p125/miniruby
08256000-08266000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
098e0000-09c5e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
40000000-4001e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 402702     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
4001e000-4001f000 r--p 0001d000 08:01 402702     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
4001f000-40020000 rw-p 0001e000 08:01 402702     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
40020000-40021000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
40021000-40023000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
40023000-40024000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
40024000-40027000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
40027000-4002e000 r--s 00000000 08:01 1454191    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
4002e000-4002f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
40039000-40050000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 402719     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so
40050000-40051000 r--p 00016000 08:01 402719     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so
40051000-40052000 rw-p 00017000 08:01 402719     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so
40052000-40054000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
40054000-4005b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 402721     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt-2.13.so
4005b000-4005c000 r--p 00006000 08:01 402721     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt-2.13.so
4005c000-4005d000 rw-p 00007000 08:01 402721     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt-2.13.so
4005d000-4005e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
4005e000-40066000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 402707     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.13.so
40066000-40067000 r--p 00007000 08:01 402707     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.13.so
40067000-40068000 rw-p 00008000 08:01 402707     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.13.so
40068000-4008f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
4008f000-400b7000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 402709     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
400b7000-400b8000 r--p 00028000 08:01 402709     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
400b8000-400b9000 rw-p 00029000 08:01 402709     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
400b9000-40231000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 402705     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
40231000-40233000 r--p 00178000 08:01 402705     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
40233000-40234000 rw-p 0017a000 08:01 402705     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
40234000-40239000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
40239000-40439000 r--p 00000000 08:01 1319567    /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
40439000-40479000 r--p 002bd000 08:01 1319567    /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
40479000-405ab000 r--p 00858000 08:01 1319567    /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
405ab000-4062c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
40642000-4065e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 394168     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
4065e000-4065f000 r--p 0001b000 08:01 394168     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
4065f000-40660000 rw-p 0001c000 08:01 394168     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
bfbc8000-bfbe9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]


[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Aborted
make: *** [exts.mk] Error 134
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install -y build-essentials libncurses5-dev
```

If they are already installed:

```
sudo apt-get reinstall -y build-essentials libncurses5-dev
```